# how to fix "uses or overrides deprecated API" and "recompile with -Xlint deprecation..."

Tags: java, swing, awt

So i'm a beginner in java and i've been encountering this problem on cmd, whenever i try to show my jframe in cmd i've been getting this note "uses or overrides deprecated API" and "recompile with -Xlint..". When i tried to erase the action listener of my enter button the jframe shows and works so i thought that it might be the code in enter.addActionListener is the problem. thank you.

```
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String userText;
    String pwdText;
    userText = uss.getText();
    pwdText = pss.getText();
    if (userText.equals("user") && pwdText.equals("pass")) {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login                         
    Successful","Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or 
    Password","Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does your IDE tell you? Does it indicate any of this code as deprecated?

Comment: no it doesn't :((

Comment: *"When i tried to erase the action listener.."* Whoa there!  What happened when you compiled with the `-Xlint` option? Compiler message advice is good advice that will likely save guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using JPasswordField and

```
pss.getText()
```

is deprecated and you have to use

```
String.valueOf(pss.getPassword())
```

If you compile with Xlint option the compiler tells you what is deprecated.